# Searching in regex using backreference

Tags: regex

Hey so i want to match multiple line in a txt file using regex **(Editpad Pro, Flavor java, it use RegexBuddy)**

```
~Example 1
[POLYLINE]
Type=0x6
Label= ABC
CountryName=Singapore
Zip=12345
RoadID=38752
Data0=(3.39466,102.48391),(3.39435,102.48413)
Nod1=0,309594,0
Nod2=19,309595,0
[END]

~Example 2
[POLYLINE]
Type=0x6
Label=CBB
CountryName=MALAYSIA
Zip=26100
RoadID=27121
RouteParam=2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Data0=(3.85552,103.36551),(3.85532,103.36563)
Nod1=0,290397,0
Nod2=1,290105,0
[END]
```

The reason i want to use backreference to match from **[POLYLINE]** to **RoadID** is because I want to **replace or add** in this case because im not replacing any of the text just add **RouteParam** between the line **RoadID** and **Data0** like in **Example 2**, So i want to write code that match **[POLYLINE]** to **RoadID** while ignoring those that already have **RouteParam** like Example 2 and to add **RouteParam** between line **RoadID** and **Data0**

so far ive used this code that will Match with POLYLINE that have no RouteParam and it works fine, but i want to use backreference so i can replace

```
(\[POLYLINE\])(?:\r?\n(?!Type).*)*\r?\n(Type=0x6)(?:\r?\n(?!RoadID).*)*\r?\n(RoadID=.+)(?:\r?\n(?!RouteParam).*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by capturing in group 1 matching `[POLYLINE]` followed by matching all the lines that do not start with either `RoadID` or `[END]` and then match RoadID

Then assert that the next line does not start with `RouteParam=` and match until the first occurrence of `[END]`

```
(\[POLYLINE](?:\r?\n(?!RoadID|\[END]).*)*\r?\nRoadID=.+\r?\n)((?:(?!RouteParam=|\[END]).*\r?\n)*\[END])
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\[POLYLINE]` Match `[POLYLINE]`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\r?\n(?!RoadID|\[END]).*` Match the whole line if it does not start with RoadID or [END]
  - `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
  - `\r?\nRoadID=.+\r?\n` Match the line that starts with RoadID=
- `)` Close group
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?!RouteParam=|\[END]).*\r?\n` Match the whole line if it does not start with RouteParam or [END]
  - `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
  - `\[END]` Match [END]
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AzLGLQ/1)

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups with the RouteParam that you want to add in between.

```
$1RouteParam=2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\n$2
```

Comment: Hey thanks and it works but the problems that i faced right now is, how do i lets say if i want to match specific group, if you look at the example **Type=0x6** in the real file im working on it has different type also like Type=0xe,Type0x7. so your code works but it also match with other Type other than Type=0x6, so i want it only to find Type=0x6 like the example, thanks man

Comment: @JohnWeck Ah I see, you mean like this https://regex101.com/r/SbWbYD/1

Comment: EXACTLY, hey thanks a lot man, appreciate it the world needs more people like u, especially new programmer lol

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you over this old question, if instead of **(add)** in the column like i ask before what if i want to **replace** at the part where there are already RouteParam for example **RouteParam=2,0,0,0 replace to RouteParam=2,1,0,0**, Thanks!

Comment: @JohnWeck It depends on how many of the rules you want to keep, but you could do it like this https://regex101.com/r/psFt5y/1

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.  Do a find and replace on the following:

```
Find:    (\[POLYLINE\].*?RoadID=\d+)(.*?\[END\])
Replace: $1\nRouteParam=2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0$2
```

### Demo

Note that the demo link above is using dot all mode.  If you don't have this available, then you may use `[\s\S]*` instead of `.*` to match across possible newlines.